# Jquery driven menu exhibits degenerative behaviour how to debug? Code examples included

Tags: jquery, runtime-error, modx, submenu

OK am going to edit this question rather than opening a new one.

Hi I have a converted a site originally built as a flat HTML site on a cherry py server into ModX, the menu is a major feature of the site, and is comprised of Jquery definitions, which are handled by a single JQuery file.

[You can see a preview version of the menu here](http://preview.compressionartifacts.co.uk/nb/)

It all works almost perfectly! The problem Im having is that having visited a section, if I move onto another one and then return to the 1st its subpages have stopped responding, no console errors are output and I can't find out where the problem is.

The code involved in handling the menus is long and hideous but heres and example of a generated link and sublink

```
menu_2 = {
    id: 'menu2',
    title: '1',
    colour: '#A70335',
    hoverColour: '#D80550',
    click: function() {
                    $('#introduction_jplayer').jPlayer("play", 0);
        MENU.show_page_content('nb/index.php?id=2');
    }
}
MENU.add_menu(menu_2);
sub_menu_42 = {
    id: 'sub_menu42',
    title: '',
    colour: '#A70335',
    hoverColour: '#D80550',
    click: function() {
        MENU.show_page_content('nb/http://');
    }
}
```

And for the brave here is the JS that deals with everything - sorry about this :)

```
(function($) {
$.fn.fade_in_sequence = function(fade_in_time, time_between) {
    /*
     * @brief Animate fade ins one after the other as a squence
     */
    time_between = typeof(time_between) == 'undefined' ? 0 : time_between;
    fade_in_time = typeof(fade_in_time) == 'undefined' ? 500 : fade_in_time;

    // The amount of remaining time until the animation is complete is initially 
    // set to the value of the entire animation duration
    var remaining_time = $(this).size() * (fade_in_time + time_between);

    var i = 0;
    return $(this).each(function() {
        // wait until previous element has finished fading and time_between has elapsed
        $(this).delay(i++ * (fade_in_time + time_between));
        remaining_time -= (fade_in_time + time_between);

        // only fade this item in if it's not on our skip list
        if ($(this).attr('id').substring(0,8) != 'not_fade') {
            $(this).fadeIn(fade_in_time, function() {
                $(".visible_arrow").filter(":first").fadeOut().removeClass("visible_arrow");
            });
        } else {                
            // we still need to keep account of the time we didn't use up fading then
            $(this).delay(fade_in_time);
        }

        // wait until the animation is over to fill up the queue.
        $(this).delay(remaining_time + time_between);
    });
};
})(jQuery);

var MENU = (function($) {
var _menu = {};
_menu.menu_items = [];
_menu.render = function() {
    /*
     * @brief draws menu on the screen
     */

    // find the menu div and add the items to it
    $.each(this.menu_items, function(index, this_menu) {
        var menu_div = '<div id="' + this_menu.id + '" class="menu_item not-selected" ' +
            'style="background-color:' + this_menu.colour + ';"> ' +
            '<div style="position: relative; top: 2.2em;">' + this_menu.title + '</div>' +
            '<span class="visible_arrow" style="position: absolute; top: 2px; left: -14px; background-color:' + this_menu.colour + ';"><img src="images/arrow.png"></span>' +
            '</div>';

        $('#menu-test').append(menu_div);

        // sort out the hover
        $('#'+this_menu.id).hover(
            function () {
                $(this).css({'background-color': this_menu.hoverColour});
            }, 
            function () {
                $(this).css({'background-color': this_menu.colour});
            }
        );

        // create a click event for the menu item
        $('#'+this_menu.id).bind('click', {click_function: this_menu.click, id: this_menu.id, sub_menu: this_menu.sub_menu}, function(event) {
            // NB-92 weirdness happens if we redraw the same menus.
            if ($('#'+this_menu.id).hasClass('selected'))
            {
                return;
            }

            // stop any previous animations
            $('.menu_item').stop(true, true).css({
                left: 0
            });

            // fade out and prepare removal of any previous sub-menu that's showing
            $('.menu_sub_item').addClass('goodbye').fadeOut(1000);
            $('.menu_sub_item').children().addClass('goodbye').fadeOut(1000);
            $('#sub_menu_image').remove();

            // mark the menu item as selected and the rest as not-selected
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected').addClass('not-selected');
            $('#'+this_menu.id).addClass('selected').removeClass('not-selected');

            // bounce out the selected menu item so the user gets some feedback
            $('.selected').animate({
                    left: '+=120'
                    }, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');

            if ( !jQuery.browser.msie ) 
            { 
                $('.selected').fadeTo(700, 1.0); 
            }
            else
            {
                // *TODO internet explorer friendly fade out
            }

            $('.selected').css({
                'background-image': 'url(images/transparent.png)'
                    });
            $('.selected').animate({
                left: 0
            }, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');

            // darken out the not-selected menu items
            if ( !jQuery.browser.msie ) 
            { 
                $('.not-selected').fadeTo(700, 0.65); 
            }
            else
            {
                // *TODO internet explorer friendly fade out
            }

            $('.not-selected').css({
                'background-image': 'url(images/semitrans.png)'
            });

            // render the new sub-menu
            $.each(event.data.sub_menu, function(index, sub_menu) {
                var menu_div = '<div id="' + sub_menu.id + '" class="menu_sub_item" ' +
                    'style="background-color:' + sub_menu.colour + '"> ' +
                    '<div style="position: relative; top: 2.2em;">' + sub_menu.title + '</div>' +
                    '</div>';

                $('#menu-test').append(menu_div);

                // sort out the hover
                $('#'+sub_menu.id).hover(
                    function () {
                        $(this).css({'background-color': sub_menu.hoverColour});
                    }, 
                    function () {
                        $(this).css({'background-color': sub_menu.colour});
                    }
                );

                // where is our top level menu item positioned?
                var position =  $('#menu-test').children(':eq(' + index + ')').position();

                // put this menu item into the right place
                $('#menu-test').children(':last').css({
                    left: position.left + 120,
                    top: position.top
                });


                // add the on click event for this sub-menu item -- much easier than the top level menus!
                $('#'+sub_menu.id).bind('click', {click_function: sub_menu.click}, function(event) {
                    if($.isFunction(event.data.click_function)) {
                        event.data.click_function();
                    }
                });

            });

            // add the arrow
            $("div[id*='not_fade']").not('.goodbye').append('<div id="sub_menu_arrow" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; top: 2px; left: -11px; background-color:' + this_menu.colour + ';"><img id="sub_menu_image" src="images/arrow.png"></div>');

            // now fade the sub menus in (delay it a bit first!)
            $('.menu_sub_item').not('.goodbye').delay(500).fade_in_sequence(400, 10);

            // and fade in the one we skipped over, and finally remove the old ones
            $("div[id*='not_fade']").delay(1200).fadeIn(1000, function() {
                $('.goodbye').remove();
            });

            // remove the next and prior buttons in case they've been left over from previous content
            $('#next').fadeOut();
            $('#prior').fadeOut();

            // and finally call the click, but only call it if it's actually a function
            if ($.isFunction(event.data.click_function)) {
                event.data.click_function();
            }

        });

    });

var width = $(window).width();
var resize_timeout = null;
    // make sure if the user re-sizes the browser, we reset
    $(window).resize(function() {
    var on_resize = function() {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected').addClass('not-selected');
        $(window.location.reload());
    }

            var new_width = $(window).width();
    // check if the new width is actually different. Internet explorer tells you when anything has resized!!!
    if ((width != new_width) && !jQuery.browser.msie)
    {
        if (resize_timeout)
                {
        window.clearTimeout(resize_timeout);
        }
        resize_timeout = window.setTimeout(on_resize, 10);
    }
    width = new_width;
    });
};


_menu.animate_intro = function() {
    /*
     * @brief show the animated intro.  This will only be seen once!
     */
    if (jQuery.browser.msie)
{
    // disable menu clicking in internet explorer, it just can't handle it!
    $('#menu-test').children().attr('disabled', 'true');
    }
    $('#main_jplayer').jPlayer("play");
    $('#menu-test').children().fade_in_sequence(500);

$('#menu-test').children(':first').animate( {left:0 }, 1, function() {
    if (jQuery.browser.msie)
    {
    // reenable menu clicking in internet explorer once the main menu is rendered
            $('#menu-test').children().removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    }).animate({
            left: '+=120'
        }, 2000, 'easeOutBounce').animate({
            left: 0
    }, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
};

_menu.animate = function(menu_item) {
    /*
     * @brief animates the menu so that menu_item is opened
     */
};

_menu.add_menu = function(menu_item, parent_id) {
    /*
     * @brief add a new menu item
     */
    if (parent_id == null) {
        // by default, we'll add to the top level menu
        // first, add a sub-menu that we can take advantage of later
        menu_item['sub_menu'] = menu_item['sub_menu'] || [];
        this.menu_items.push(menu_item);
    } else {
        // find the parent_id in the menu, and add to the contents
        $.each(this.menu_items, function(index, this_menu) {
            if (this_menu.id == parent_id) {
                this_menu.sub_menu.push(menu_item);
            }
        });
    }
};

_menu.show_page_content = function(page_content_name) {
    /*
     * @brief Grab content from the server and shove it into the content area
     */
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/' + page_content_name,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html) {
            $('#page_content').fadeTo(
                700, 0, function() {
                $(this).html(html).fadeTo(
                    700, 1
                );
            });
        }
    });
};

return _menu;
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hardly someone will help you as long as do not show an url or code.

Comment: Code and link added if you care to take another look :) I still cant work out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out what the problem was,

Basically I missed an ID on the first menu item which meant that this line was never carried out:

```
// and fade in the one we skipped over, and finally remove the old ones
        $("div[id*='not_fade']").delay(1200).fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $('.goodbye').remove();
        });
```

This meant that old menu items were never removed from the page flow and remained interferring with user clicks. For the moment I've amended the code as follows:

```
// and fade in the one we skipped over, and finally remove the old ones
            $('.goodbye').fadeOut().delay(1000).remove();
```

This doesnt fade out the items with a class of goodbye but it does at least remove them so the menu is useable.